# Need to know how to add more values to String

Tags: java, string

I want to know how to add more values in new String(), as it only lets me enter one, eg Burgers.

The code is as follows:

```
String txt = new String("Burgers","Cheese");
```

Comment: You should specify the language you are using every language has different way to do so !

Comment: It is in Java, sorry

Comment: A string is a string, not a list of strings or a vector of strings or a set of strings.

Comment: that is wrong constructor you can't create string with two parameters.

Comment: yes string is sequence of characters. you can not add values to it, as for that you can increase the string adding string characters to it using StringBuilder or StringBuffer class which in turn will be new String.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
String[] txt = {"Burgers","Cheese","John Cena"};
```

Comment: Should I make an array?

Answer (score 0):

Property class and method depends on what you expect after.
If you wait String[] use `String[] txt = {"Burgers","Cheese"};`

If you except string line with comma delimiter  "Burgers,Cheese", use `new StringJoiner(",").add("Burgers").add("Cheese").toString()`

If you don't need delimiter simply user `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

**new String("burger")** Initializes a newly created String object.
Thus, for the constructor, you can pass any single character sequence(ex: "burger")  as the argument.

If you want to store multiple strings, what you have to do is using a data structure(ex: array) to store more than one string. for that purpose, you can use the code below.

```
String[] foodItmes = {"Burger","sandwich"};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need single string made up of multiple strings... you could use do so :

```
String st = new String("Burger");
st = st + "cheese";
```

Or

use StringBuilder like so :

```
String finalString = new StringBuilder("Burgers").append("cheese").toString();
```

If you need an array of strings you could do what @sorxrob suggested. If you need a list of strings you can use :

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
str.add("burger");
str.add("cheese");
```

It totally depends on how you intend to use it.

Comment: In that case you should use list or fixed size array. Read the strings and add them in list. Do this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<String>stringList=new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("Burger");
stringList.add("Cheese");
stringList.add("MoreThing");
stringList.add("Even more");
//.....
//To access value, e.g. first value.
String v1= stringList.get(0);

//Print value
System.out.println(v1);
```

EDIT (This is edit for using Scanner):
If you want to get console user input you can do as follows:
For example if you run this program will let you enter string
separated by comma, like Cheese,Burger,Pie,Fruit

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter comma separated string: ...");
    String[] s=(sc.nextLine()).split(",");

    //E.g: Access/Print second value:
    System.out.println(s[1]+"\n\nAll:");

   //E.g: If you want to print all:
   for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
      System.out.println(s[i]);
   }
  }

}
```

This is complete Java program, try to compile it and run to see how it works:

compile: javac Example.java

Run: java Example

Comment: Need to use with Scanner and System.in